# Why R library 'ssw' cannot find python module installed via pip3, although pip3 module installation is satisfied?

Tags: python, r, configuration, pip, bioinformatics

I am on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS focal`, and using `R`. I want to install in R a library to perform local sequence alignments based upon the Smith-Waterman algorithm but via a faster implementation.

The `R` library is **ssw** and can be found here:  `https://github.com/nanxstats/ssw-r` [click link to github repo](https://github.com/nanxstats/ssw-r)

description: *ssw-r offers an R interface for SSW, a fast implementation of the Smith-Waterman algorithm for sequence alignment using SIMD. ssw-r is currently built on the Python package ssw-py*

When I try to install it following the README.md steps,

- `remotes::install_github("nanxstats/ssw-r")`, executes fine
- `reticulate::use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3")`, also executes fine
- `library("ssw")`, loading the library even executes fine
- `"ACGT" %>% align("TTTTACGTCCCCC")`, running an example does not execute fine producing this error:

```
> "ACGT" %>% align("TTTTACGTCCCCC")
Error: Python module ssw was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         /root/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
libpython:      /root/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.6m.so
pythonhome:     /root/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate:/root/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.11 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Aug  5 2020, 20:09:42)  [GCC 7.5.0]
numpy:          /root/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1
```

I have installed `ssw-py` as the README.md requested via;

```
$ sudo pip3 install ssw-py
Requirement already satisfied: ssw-py in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.2.6)
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the dependencies. When installing `ssw` in R the first time I was prompted whether I wanted to install `miniconda` and chose yes. I do not have `anaconda` installed on the system. (*On Ubuntu bionic 18.04 I was able to install anaconda successfully and no matter how many times I tried on focal it would not work, eg the installer originally placed it in /root/anaconda3 in a small file*)

What do I need to fix to get this library `ssw` to work?

Comment: If you are trying to use pip to install into a Conda environment, then `pip3` is not correct. Conda does not use such an alias, but instead will have simply `pip` prioritized on PATH when the environment is activated. `pip3` points back to a system-level Python, which the results clearly show.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by using this command prior to the statement `library("ssw")`:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "/usr/bin/python3")
```

The statement prescribed in the README.md `reticulate::use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3")` did not connect to the python installation and this one works on my system. This was discovered via:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

and then using this directory as the system environment for the python connectivity