# Anaconda3 installation procedure placed installation in unexpected directory and conda commands don't work under Ubuntu focal 20

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I am using `Ubuntu 20 focal` and am having problems with the `Anaconda` installation process and operation. Using the file: `Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh`, and running via: `sudo bash Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh`
I press `ENTER` after the welcome message, go through all the agreement messages and press `yes` that I agree, and then see the response:

```
Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'
>>> yes

Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/root/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/root/anaconda3] >>>
```

I then press `ENTER`, the installation takes place and now there is an installation at

```
$ sudo ls /root/
anaconda3
```

But, after this the commands expected to work do not,eg;

```
$ conda list
conda: command not found
```

I cannot use conda uninstall commands and wonder how the installation procedure should have taken place. The installation has not placed any files in `~/`.

I have a `Julia lang` installation as well and there is a reference to it from an environments.txt file;

```
$ ls ~/.conda/
environments.txt
usr3@usr3:~$ ls ~/.conda/environments.txt 
.conda/environments.txt
usr3@usr3:~$ head ~/.conda/environments.txt 
/home/usr3/.julia/conda/3
usr3@usr3:~$ ls /home/usr3/.julia/conda/
3/       deps.jl  
usr3@usr3:~$ ls /home/usr3/.julia/conda/3/
bin/                         installer.sh
compiler_compat/             lib/
condabin/                    LICENSE.txt
conda-meta/                  pkgs/
condarc-julia.yml            share/
envs/                        shell/
etc/                         ssl/
include/                     x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/
```

Comment: Is `sudo` actually needed? That is mostly for system admins managing a multi-user install; typical install never requires elevated privileges.

Comment: @merv, I used `sudo` out of habit. It came without thinking. After trying without sudo, the installation recommended a directory that was expected `>>> yes Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location: /home/resort/anaconda3   - Press ENTER to confirm the location  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation   - Or specify a different location below [/home/usr3/anaconda3] >>>  ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/home/resort/anaconda3' If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.` Although this seems like progress this new installation didn't engage `conda`

Comment: Did you run `/home/resort/anaconda3/bin/conda init`, then restart the shell?

Comment: @merv, `/home/resort/anaconda3/bin` does not have a `conda-init` file. it has other files, eg `conda-build`

Comment: It should have simply `conda`; the `init` is an argument.

Comment: @merv, well, that did it! Thanks alot! can you put your comments into an answer so I can award it to you? Why do I have `base` before the username on the terminal now? Is it of concern? Also, by any chance if you have any understanding of this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236638/why-r-library-ssw-cannot-find-python-module-installed-via-pip3-although-pip3  your insight would be appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222694/discussion-between-vass-and-merv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected installation location in OP is likely due to running the installer with elevated privileges (`sudo bash ...`). Typically, only system administrators and others managing a multi-user install should require elevated privileges. The default install should not use `sudo`, which will instead result in installing somewhere under the user's home.

I haven't run the installer in a while, but I thought that it now includes an automatic run of `conda init` as part of the install. If not, please consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918) with details on how to set up Conda's shell functionality (e.g., `conda activate`).